# How to execute an external application with Python?

Tags: python

I want to execute an external Windows application from my python program, but I don't want to give the whole path to the application, because I need it to work on any computer.

For example, I want to open chrome without having to give the whole path to the application because it can be different on other Windows computers. Is there any way of doing it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what if the pc doesn't have chrome? It might be possible to get windows default internet browser app

Comment: The most portable way of opening a browser on any platform is with [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to run specifically web browsers you can use the python [Web browser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html)!

If it's not necessarily a web browser and you know the file will be stored consistently relative to your python file you can use relative paths.
Try some of these commands to see what you can get and you can use os.path.join() command to move relatively in your directory system

```
import os
import sys

absolutepath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(absolutepath)

fileDirectory = os.path.dirname(absolutepath)
print(fileDirectory)
#Path of parent directory
parentDirectory = os.path.join(path, os.pardir)
print(parentDirectory)
#Navigate to Strings directory
newPath = os.path.join(parentDirectory, 'Strings')   
print(newPath)
```

Alternatively if you don't know the relative path either the only thing I can think of is search recursively in the folder/subfolders you expect the file to be in.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module thanks to a comment just with *webbrowser.open("web page you want to open name")* and it will open your browser with the link you provided.